# image_picker_android:debugUnitTestRuntimeClasspath

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, gradle, flutter-dependencies

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':image_picker_android:debugUnitTestRuntimeClasspath'.
> Failed to transform bcprov-jdk15on-1.68.jar (org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.68) to match attributes {artifactType=processed-jar, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: /Users/thor/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.68/46a080368d38b428d237a59458f9bc915222894d/bcprov-jdk15on-1.68.jar.
> > Failed to transform '/Users/thor/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.68/46a080368d38b428d237a59458f9bc915222894d/bcprov-jdk15on-1.68.jar' using Jetifier. Reason: IllegalArgumentException, message: Unsupported class file major version 59. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)
> Suggestions:
> - Check out existing issues at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:460323&s=modified_time:desc, it's possible that this issue has already been filed there.
> - If this issue has not been filed, please report it at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=460323 (run with --stacktrace and provide a stack trace if possible).

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 18s

Answer (score 4):

**I added following lines in the android section of app level build.gradle of my  project.**

```
   lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
        disable "Instantiatable"
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
```

And every thing started to work fine.
[Check out my Gradle File](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/learning-firebase-2d636.appspot.com/o/build.gradle?alt=media&token=801bbb4a-6560-45f7-88de-7d9b594f3dfe)

Answer (score 4):

I tried adding the following under `buildTypes { release {...` of `android/app/build.grade`

```
buildTypes {

    release {

        lintOptions {

            disable 'InvalidPackage'
            disable "Instantiatable"
            checkReleaseBuilds false
            abortOnError false

        }

        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are not many things to do just go to **android/app/build.grade** and add this line

```
  lintOptions { 
    
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        }
```

to your code after `android {` like

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 31

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }
    lintOptions { 

    checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
```